# Flutter app expanding behind navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android

After hours of trial and error, I gave up.
Can somebody tell me why my app is expanding behind the virtual navigation buttons?

I tried swiching and inserting SafeArea, Flex, Expanded and so on but have not found which Widget is creating this behaviour.

[image: Overflow at the bottom]

My Code:

```js
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    // direction: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        // child:Text("test text", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),)
        child: Container(
            // color: Colors.red,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _input_controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: _font_size),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              showCursor: false,
              readOnly: true,
              // decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your number"),
              // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              // inputFormatters: [
              //   // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
              //   // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[.,']")),
              //   CardFormatter
              // ], // Only numbers can be entered
            )),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        // child:Text("test text", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),)
        child: Container(
            // color: Colors.red,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _answer_controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: _font_size),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              showCursor: false,
              readOnly: true,
              // decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your number"),
              // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              // inputFormatters: [
              //   // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
              //   // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[.,']")),
              //   CardFormatter
              // ], // Only numbers can be entered
            )),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        // child:Text("test text", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.green),)
        child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.2),
            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
            children: List.generate(
                20,
                (i) => Container(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(i);
                        },
                        child: Text(i.toString()),
                      ),
                    ))),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
  }        crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                        children: List.generate(
  20,
  (i) => Container(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(i);
          },
          child: Text(i.toString()),
        ),
      )),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    
  }
```

Comment: It will be GridView.count, the children of the gridview have a predefined size, you must customize them, if you look a scroll was generated right in the area of the buttons of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, when you ask, you get the answer shortly after by yourself (with a hint from Chance)

Putting GridView inside Expanded causes this behaviour, if you put GridView inside a Container you get an assertion error, add shrinkWrap: true to the Constructor of GridView and everything works as expected:

```js
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("Text1")),
      Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("Text1")),
      Container(
        child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            mainAxisSpacing: 0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: List.generate(
                20,
                (i) => Container(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(i);
                        },
                        child: Text(i.toString()),
                      ),
                    ))),
      )
    ],
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your screen height doesn't cover the Full widget height. That's why the `GridView` is behind the screen. If you scroll down, you will get the rest of the button. You can play with `childAspectRatio` to reduce the height.

If you like to have everything in withing screen, you can use Stack and `LayoutBuilder` to measure the screen size. But it is nice to have scroll-effect for small screen but I will prefer full scroll body, In that case you can use `SingleChildScrollView` on `body` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` on gridView.

You can check my [repo](https://github.com/yeasin50/Calculator) I was testing year ago.